# Moq how to correctly mock set only properties

Tags: c#, .net, moq

What is the correct way for dealing with interfaces the expose set-only properties with Moq? Previously I've added the other accessor but this has bled into my domain too far with random `throw new NotImplementedException()` statements throughout.

I just want to do something simple like:

`mock.VerifySet(view => view.SetOnlyValue, Times.Never());`

But this yields a compile error of `The property 'SetOnlyValue' has no getter`

Comment: I am confused, what's the purpose of the test if the compiler picks up the fact that you try to call a getter on a write only property? I am sure I am missing something here, perhaps a clarification from OP?

Comment: @Igor Zevaka and others: `view => view.SetOnlyValue' generates `The property 'SetOnlyValue' has no getter'. This is because this piece of code is being interpreted as a call to a getter. In the read-write case, `VerifySet` walks the expression and figures out that what's wanted is an expectation on the setter of the property. In the write-only case, this runs into a compiler error. We need to assume that the OP is not stupid here and isnt trying to cause work for himself and is instead asking 'how do I avoid having to do extra junk'.

Comment: Oh i get it. So it was about setting up a verification in moq that didn't rely on a property requiring a getter, correct?

Comment: @Ruben No, there's no longer a point since you pointed out that it's a set only property, which I had looked over before. My mistake.

Comment: hi. I've been through this answer, just looking for a double-check. So, if I have a setter-only property and I don't care about the value, I **cannot** use `VerifySet(v => v.SetOnlyProp)`. Instead I **have** to use `VerifySet(v => v.SetOnlyProp = It.IsAny<X>())`. Is that right?

Comment: @superjos yes, exactly! The first verifyset is an Action that is invoking the getter of SetOnlyProp, they turn that into an expression for the setter. However since that property has no getter you get a build failure. When you use the 2nd verifyset you are directly creating the expression.

Comment: Great (that I got it, the thing itself sucks a litte :)) Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public class Xyz
{
    public virtual string AA { set{} }
}
public class VerifySyntax
{
    [Fact]
    public void ThisIsHow()
    {
        var xyz = new Mock<Xyz>();
        xyz.Object.AA = "bb";
        // Throws:
        xyz.VerifySet( s => s.AA = It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Never() );
    }
}
public class SetupSyntax
{
    [Fact]
    public void ThisIsHow()
    {
        var xyz = new Mock<Xyz>();
        xyz.SetupSet( s => s.AA = It.IsAny<string>() ).Throws( new InvalidOperationException(  ) );
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>( () => xyz.Object.AA = "bb" );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - Having read this, I deleted my answer since it seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Lee: Cool, ta (I know I did a double take reading the question too!)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I never would've randomly decided to put an It.IsAny expression next to a line that resharper says is a compile error!

Comment: I did know you could specifically test for setting but I never though that would actually change the method overload that's being called by SetupSet to get around the compile error.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: Not sure if I'm explaining myself clearly. I mean that the Expression `view => view.SetOnlyValue` invokes the getter whereas something like `view => view.SetOnlyValue = 0` will invoke the setter. To avoid having to use the `It` stuff, the first style (getter) in the context of a `Setup/VerifySet` gets interpreted as referring to the setter, even though the underlying code is a getter invocation. There's no magic of the kind I feel you're interpreting my previous answer as suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Ruben!

And to help someone with a VB.Net gotcha this is the same code in VB.Net:

```vb
Public Interface Xyz
    WriteOnly Property AA As String
End Interface
Public Class VerifySyntax
    <Fact()>
    Public Sub ThisIsHow()
        Dim xyz = New Mock(Of Xyz)
        xyz.Object.AA = "bb"
        ' Throws:
        xyz.VerifySet(Sub(s) s.AA = It.IsAny(Of String)(), Times.Never())
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class SetupSyntax
    <Fact()>
    Public Sub ThisIsHow()
        Dim xyz = New Mock(Of Xyz)
        xyz.SetupSet(Sub(s) s.AA = It.IsAny(Of String)()).Throws(New InvalidOperationException())
        Assert.Throws(Of InvalidOperationException)(Sub() xyz.Object.AA = "bb")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Important here is that you *can't* use a single-line **Function** lambda since this will be interpreted as an expression that returns a value, rather than the assignment statement that you are after.
This is since VB.Net uses the single equal sign not only for assignment but also for equality comparison, and so trying to do

```vb
        xyz.VerifySet(Function(s) s.AA = It.IsAny(Of String)(), Times.Never())
```

will be interpreted as a boolean comparison of the s.AA-value and the It.IsAny(Of String)(), thus invoking the getter, which will again result in a compile error.
Instead you want to use a **Sub** lambda (or possibly a multi-line Function lambda).

If you have a getter on the property, however, a Function lambda will still work.