# Verify property is never set using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, properties, moq, verify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moq - How to verify that a property value is set via the setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641919/moq-how-to-verify-that-a-property-value-is-set-via-the-setter)

I would expect the following test to fail:

```
public interface IObjectWithProperty
{
    int Property { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Property_ShouldNotBeCalled()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IObjectWithProperty>();

    mock.Object.Property = 10;

    mock.Verify(x => x.Property, Times.Never());
}
```

However, this test passes, even though `Property` is clearly accessed on the line before the `Verify`.

So it seems that `Verify` actually means `VerifyGet`.

How should I verify that a property is never set?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

`mock.VerifySet(x => x.Property = It.IsAny<int>(), Times.Never());`

Comment: Thanks, this works. The syntax seems like an easy trap to fall into, as it looks like the code is being tested when in fact it isn't. Will have to go and search my code for `Verify(*, Times.Never())` now...