# How to check setter is not called for a moq object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I have a property. In my unit-test I want to make sure that set is not called. How I can achieve this?

I have able to check that value is set, but how can I make sure that it is not set.

```
public ISomeInterface
{
    bool? SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


public SomeClass
{
    SomeClass(ISomeInterface someInterface)
    {    _someInterface = someInterface;    }

    public void SomeMethod(bool condition)
    {
         if (condition)
              _someInterface.SomeProperty = true;
    }
}

// Test
var moq = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
var target = new SomeClass(moq.Object);

target.SomeMethod(false);

// Check here that someInterface.SomeProperty set is not called.
moq.VerifySet(i => i.SomePropery = true); // This checks that set is called. But how to check if it is not called?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify property is never set using Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608382/verify-property-is-never-set-using-moq)

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moq.VerifySet(i => i.SomePropery = true,Time.Never);` should do it.

But I'd be more inclined to just test that the value of `SomeProperty` was false after the `SUT` is exercised, in order to decouple the actual behaviour (that `SomeProperty` does not *end up* as false, regardless of *how* it gets there) from the actual implementation details (that `SomeProperty` is never directly set).

e.g you might refactor your code later on to

```
public void SomeMethod(bool condition)
{
    _someInterface.SomeProperty = SomeOtherComponent.MakeTheDecision(condition)
}
```

Meaning your test will be *guaranteed* to fail and worse yet, will be meaningless in terms of the actual value of `_someInterface` (because it is always `set` in that case)

Note this means having a `public` accessor on `SomeProperty` that you can access from your test code; if you don't want to do that then you are testing a private member which is not really the point of unit testing - you should be testing public implementation only.

Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

Calling .VerifyAll() may also be helpful :D